# How to play the audiobook .m4b file in julia?

Tags: web, audio, ffmpeg, file-io, julia

I want to play a audio book file `xxx.m4b` in a web app, but I can't find a package to handle the m4b file. I find a possible package called `ffmpeg` but I have no idea how to implement it. How can I play a audio book file in a web app or just natively in my desktop?

Comment: crosspost: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-play-the-audiobook-m4b-file-in-julia/69091/3

Comment: I don't know how to _play_ it, but this is how you could convert it to mp3: `using FFMPEG; ffmpeg_exe(\`-i "m4b.m4b" -acodec libmp3lame -ar 22050 "m4b.mp3"\`)`

Comment: Can I use julia to control the playback? Like the start time or speed. I want it to be a web stream. It is like user click a bottom on the web page and send a http post to julia, and the julia control the web stream? I’m wondering how to get the .m4b file to a audio stream and connect the stream to the web.

Comment: It matters whether the file is encrypted, as some audiobooks are, since if it is encrypted you would have to send the file to an app that supports its encryption method.